# Destiny Weapon XP bonus applies to bounties?

Tags: destiny

You can get weapon XP bonus boost from the consumables Xur sells and also the grimoire bonuses.  Does this bonus only apply to kills, or do you also get bonus xp for turning in bounties?  So for examle if i turn in a 5,000XP bounty, if i have bonuses active do i get 5000 + bonus xp?

Comment: Additionally, what about the bonus from doing the Nightfall strike?

Comment: Not sure if Nightfall bonus helps - it may? @Sammyjackalaz is probably spot on with bounties not affecting telemetries. However, bounties are still the quickest way to level a gun, and aren't usually hard or time-consuming if you pick wisely.

Comment: If we can ever get some sort of metric to go by instead of a randomly filling bar this wouldn't be a question!

Answer (score 2):

The weapon telemetry you are talking about as I know, only applies to the experience earned from kills and nothing else. The grimoire bonuses do not include getting more experience from bounties at least from what is stated on their website: Bungie.net, under grimoire on the left then, bonuses at the top tab. So no sorry, no bonuses active will affect the amount of experience earned from bounties. :(

Comment: Actually the Nightfall bonus applies xp bonuses to guns from every aspect that normally would (bounties, kills, and other xp gain that is applied to guns)